# Why this mysql statement returns whole table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am wondering that how this query returns all data from the table:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ''=' 'or'';
```

It gives the same output of this:

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

It is probably works as this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE true;
```

but, WHY?

Comment: Are you searching for empty emails? Can you share sample data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break the `WHERE` condition down, and this starts to make sense:

```
email = ''
```

All rows with an `email` attribute set to a blank string `''` will return `TRUE`. For a minute, let's assume that all rows in your `users` table do not meet this condition, and will return `FALSE` when this query is run. That leads us to the next comparison:

```
FALSE=' '
```

This comparison returns `TRUE`; this functionality is explained well in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782594/mysql-space-equals-empty-string) - basically, the single whitespace character is treated as a trailing space and is thus truncated by the engine for the purposes of comparison. [The resulting blank string is "falsy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181980/mysql-select-where-column-is-falsey) in MySQL, which would make `FALSE=FALSE` evaluate to `TRUE`.

Evaluated, this would look in all something like

```
WHERE TRUE or FALSE
```

... which would return all your rows.

---

While outside the scope of the question, it's not particularly clear what your original query is trying to achieve. If you're looking for empty e-mail address fields in your table, [don't over-complicate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470813/how-do-i-check-if-a-column-is-empty-or-null-in-mysql).

Comment: Excellent explanation! It was a question out of curiosity.